# React- redux online example should not work

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am studying react-redux using the official guide:

https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial

In this guide there is the link to the example project:

https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo

In this example there is a part that I am unable to understand how could work.

The issue (i.e the part that I am unable to understand) is in the file src/redux/store.js

In this file there is an import statement:

```
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
```

but in the directory tree there is no rootReducer defined and exported in any of the file in the whole project.

How can the app ever work?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
import <something> from 'somePath'
```

`somePath` is usually a relative path to a file, or to a module in `node_modules`, but it can *also* be a path to a *folder* which contains an `index.js` file.

Here, there's a folder named `reducers` in the same directory, and that folder contains an `index.js` file which does:

```
export default combineReducers({ todos, visibilityFilter });
```

So `import rootReducer from "./reducers";` points to that `index.js` file in the nested folder, and puts its default export into the `rootReducer` variable.

This is not specific to React or Redux - this is universal for `import` syntax in JavaScript.

For example, if `app.js` contains `import something from './components'`, both file system structures below will result in the path resolving successfully:

```
|- app.js
|- components (folder)
   | index.js
   | componentA.js
   | componentB.js
```

```
|- app.js
|- components.js
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple:

```js
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
```

will automatically look inside the `reducers`-folder for an file called index.EXTENSION.

If you look into `src/reduc/reducers/index.js` you will see the following like:

```js
export default combineReducers({ todos, visibilityFilter });
```

which is actually exporting what the example-project is importing in `src/redux/store.js`.